# Are there root folder naming restrictions?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have created a small project in VC Code using TypeScript and Node.js under Windows. I happened to name the root folder with brackets in the name, e.g. `xyz (first)`. With this, the import statement would fail and all sorts of weird things happened. After renaming to `xyz first`everything behaves nicely.

Are there any restrictions described for the root folder name, or any other folder names for that matter?

Comment: spaces in filenames often result in problems

Comment: But it's the bracket ( ), not the space that causes the issue. Any documentation on what's a legal folder name for VS code?

Comment: any name the OS supports, but also look what the language `import` statements support, like No-Space in Python module paths

Comment: The import statement was `import { Folder, PlainFile } from "./filesystemObject";`Is it possible that the base folder name creeps in somehow?

Comment: of course, the file is accessed by its full path